# How to set a margin in UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I'm currently developing a simple text-editing app for iPad.
I want to set left/right margins like the attached picture.
Just adding UITextView into another UIView with larger width won't work because a scroll indicator won't be properly located.

Instead of UIView, I added UITextView into UIScrollView, and it works almost fine. But they sometimes show strange behaviors, and UITextViewDelegate doesn't work with my UIViewController.

Is there any way to set left/right margins only using UITextView?
Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You can use the property **textContainerInset**

Following the example of *George Green*:

```
myTextView.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
```

Answer (score 6):

UITextView is a subclass of UIScrollView. I haven't tried it but you could try something like:

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 10.0f, 0.0f, 10.0f);
```

UIEdgeInsetsMake() is as follows:

```
UIEdgeInsets UIEdgeInsetsMake (
   CGFloat top,
   CGFloat left,
   CGFloat bottom,
   CGFloat right
);
```

So you should be able to inset your textView content.

Hope this helps, let me know if it works!! :)

Comment: This doesn't quite work for me. Sure, the margins are added, but they are added outside the bounds of the UITextView. The result is a text display that starts out flush with the edge, but you can scroll it out to the margin. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to do the same thing, but textview.contentInset didn't work.

I put UITextView with a narrow width on UIView, then move the scrollview indicator of textview to the right side, so I got what I wanted really well.

textView.clipsToBounds = NO;
textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -20.0f);

This answer might help.
[Is there a way to put UITextView's scroll indicator to outside UITextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343390/is-there-a-way-to-put-uitextviews-scroll-indicator-to-outside-uitextview)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the scroller right inset value of the UITextView to negative value and disable the clip subview option to achieve your require. No other scrollview is needed.
[image: Select textview on storyboard first]

In code it would be

```
textView.clipsToBounds = NO;
textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f);
```