# Is there a way to put UITextView's scroll indicator to outside UITextView?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

It might be a silly question.
I'm trying to set left/right margins like the attached picture. I succeeded to implement it by adding UITextView to UIScrollView.
However, I could achieve almost everything I want with UITextView alone. For example, with UIScrollView, when I manually change the text of UITextView, it automatically scrolls to bottom regardless of setting its .scrollEnabled to No.

It would be perfect if a scroll indicator of UITextView appears outside UITextView.
In the attached picture, let's say the red box represents the entire UITextView. I tried to change UITextView's scrollIndicatorInsets property, but a scroll indicator can be moved only inward to be visible.

Several apps such as Pages, aWriter, Plaintext achieve this feature.
Could you give any suggestion?

Thank you!

I [image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can set the scroller right inset value of the UITextView to negative value and disable the clip subview option to achieve your require. No other scrollview is needed.
[image]

Comment: It works perfectly!! I googled a few days, and I chose the way of adding UITextView as a subview to UIScrollView to achieve this. This inefficient way makes me to take a lot of time to correct anon-clear relationship between UITextView and UIScrollView. Thank you so much!!

Comment: In code this would be `textView.clipsToBounds = NO; textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -50.0f);`

Comment: for some reason setting clipsToBounds on the storyboard didnt work, had to be done in code

Comment: @dvs this works but you still need to use a container to clip the contents from scrolling outside of the bounds

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively you could set the Right contentInset property.

Comment: This will make the horizontal scroll enabled. Not recommend.

Comment: logsTableView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = NO; wil prevent this

Answer (score 2):

```
UIEdgeInsets insets =  textView.scrollIndicatorInsets;
insets.right += 5; //add what ever is your margain
textView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
```